# how to convert a string to list I have a string how to convert it to a list?

Tags: python

I have a string like: string = "[1, 2, 3]"

I need to convert it to a list like: [1, 2, 3]

I've tried using regular expression for this purpose, but to no avail

Comment: use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: or use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) if your data is json.

Answer (score 4):

```py
string = "[1, 2, 3]"

import ast
ast.literal_eval(string)
```

would evaluate to `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Agree that `ast.literal_eval()` is the correct approach here, but on the off chance that the OP has json then `json.loads(string)` would also do the trick.

Comment: Grateful to you

Answer (score 2):

Try
`[int(x) for x in arr.strip("[]").split(", ")]`, or if your numbers are floats you can do `[float(x) for x in arr.strip("[]").split(", ")]`

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that your string value comes from a safe source or if it is just an academic thing, you can make use of `eval` (as pointed out in the comments for this answer).

```
>>> str_value = "[1, 2, 3]"
>>> list_value = eval(str_value)
>>> type(list_value)
<class 'list'>
>>> list_value[0]
1
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), when using **eval**, `the expression argument is parsed and evaluated as a python expression`, so this can lead to malicious code execution, depending on the context you are planning to use such evaluation.

```
>>> str_value = "print('hello')"
>>> eval(str_value)
hello
```

If you cannot guarantee such source or if your actual intent is evaluating python literal expressions, you can make use of `ast.literal_eval` (as pointed out in the comments for this answer).

```
>>> import ast
>>> str_value = "[1, 2, 3]"
>>> list_value = ast.literal_eval(str_value)
>>> type(list_value)
<class 'list'>
>>> list_value[0]
1
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), when using **ast.literal_eval**, `the string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.`, so it can be evaluated without leading to malicious code execution.

```
>>> str_value = "print('hello')"
>>> ast.literal_eval(str_value)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  [...]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 63, in _raise_malformed_node
    raise ValueError(f'malformed node or string: {node!r}')
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x7f4b0d501a00>
```

Comment: `eval` can be dangerous, because the string _could_ have malicious code in it. Usually, `eval` can be replaced with something else. In this case, using `ast.literal_eval` or string methods would be safer (and better imho). If you edit this answer with some caveats about `eval`, I'll happily remove the downvote.

Comment: @jakub, thank you very much for the clarification, you are correct!